# API Metodo de Autenticacao GET

Tags: java, api, intellij-idea

boa Noite,
Estou com dificuldade para fazer o uma Método GET com Autenticação funcionar
Li a Documentação e instalei o SDK no IntelliJ IDEA de uma API de Exchange e estou com dificuldade para fazer o código abaixo funcionar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que devo ceder alguns parâmetros específicos como Api Key e Secret Key
porem o que não estou entendo e esse Método **executeRequest(request)**
pois no SDK que baixei nao possui esse método...
Alguém pode me dar uma pista de como resolver isso?

Um Treco da Documentacao da API que trata sobre essa chamada:
https://doc.novadax.com/pt-BR/#comunicacao-com-a-api

***Método de Autenticação**
Passos para autenticar uma requisição GET

1. Query string é
   queryStr = "name=joao&cpf=123456&birthday=2017-08-01"
2. Codifique a query string de consulta e ordene parâmetros seguindo a ordem ASCII.
   sort(urlencode(queryStr)) // birthday=2017-08-01&cpf=123456&name=joao
3. Transforme a string com formato {método de requisição}\n{caminho de requisição}\n{string a ser codificada}\n{timeStamp}
   signStr = GET\n/v1/orders/get\nbirthday=2017-08-01&cpf=123456&name=joao\n1564988445199
4. Utilize a string gerada no passo 3 e sua "SecretKey" para autenticar sua requisição
   sign = hmac_sha256(signStr,SecretKey)
5. Adicione Accesskey, Signature e TimeStamp para o cabeçalho (header) da requisição.
   request.header.add("X-Nova-Access-Key",AccessKey)
   request.header.add("X-Nova-Signature",Sign)
   request.header.add("X-Nova-Timestamp",TimeStamp)*

Comment: Por favor substituitua a imagem por código em texto, esta nas regras do site para não usar código como imagem.